# Use styled components conditional props with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm getting the error below when I try to use logical && in a styled component prop
When I use the optional chaining "? :", It works without any ts error but can't use "&&"

using:

- typescript: 4.0.5
- react: 18.2.0
- react-scripts: 4.0.3
- styled-components: 2.1.2

```
Type 'false | InterpolationValue[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & ContainerProps, any>>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & ContainerProps, any>>'
```

Below is my code:

```
const hoverfragment = css`
  &:hover {
      display: unset;
  }
`;

interface ContainerProps {
  selected?: boolean;
}

const container = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;

  ${({ selected }) => selected && hoverfragment} // This is where the error is
`;
```

Comment: It's weird, but I reproduce your code and got no error. Please can you tell from what and where you get your error? Does it crush your app?

Comment: Don't get any errors while running your code. Could you please edit your question to include any more relevant code to show where it fails?

Comment: @AndriiVynarchuk No it doesnt crash my app, it just displays this error on vscode